# Media Queries div size

Tags: html, css

I am a beginner and I'm still learning. Why width of div `.person-details` does not change in this case 50% of the original resolution of less than `1024px`? The problem in the picture attached.

[image]

Comment: Please provide the code as well.

Comment: `.person-details` is probably lower in your CSS and overwriting those styles because of how CSS priority works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your custom css is overwriting column width. You see how the column width of 50% is crossed out because you have a custom style for .person-details?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes I have class ".large-6" in mixin.scss and ".personal-details" in base.scss. How can I fix this ?

EDIT: Ok Guys, I put mixin.scss at the bottom of the list styles. Thanks for asking.